# Pre-compiling an existing web application on the fly

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-server-2008-r2, precompile

We have an asp web application (main company site) sitting on windows server 2008 r2. At the begining the site is small but later on around 500K aspx pages are added to the site (for SEO purposes, may be not right content but that's different issue)

We want to edit user control which is linked through the application (in 500K pages), if we modify the user control web site needs pre-compiling, i tried doing that manually using

```
aspnet_compiler -v virtualPath targetPath
```

form MSDN site [as here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) , but the site taking atleast two days to precompile the whole site.

Which is big issue for my boss as most business depending on SEO.

```
Server Specs 

OS: Windows server 2008 R2
4 Cores
6 GB Ram
```

Looking for any other ways to resolve this issue. thanks

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a good solution to this other than "get better hardware" or "change the way you're doing things". 500,000 pages is insane. It sounds like what you need is SEO-friendly routing. This might get you going in the right direction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Now, you confusing me here. You said, you have `...asp web application ...`. But you talking as if you have an asp website, actually. If you have website, you don't need to precompile anything. Just drop your new code  and it will compile next time it is requested. And if you feel, you "need" to precompile, do it on different machine and then re-deploy.

Comment: TS: its a web application with .cs files

Comment: If this is web application, than you generating a single DLL and you can compile it on different machine prior to deployment.

Comment: Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398860%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I read that ages ago. in fact used inplace compilation on my website, it compiles the site, but when users trying to visit the site it starts compiling again and server stucks. looking for any alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers

use the bellow tool

```
aspnet_compiler  [-?]
                 [-m metabasePath | -v virtualPath [-p physicalPath]]
                 [[-u] [-f] [-d] [-fixednames] targetDir]
                 [-c]
                 [-errorstack]
                 [-nologo]
                 [[-keyfile file | -keycontainer container ] [-aptca] [-delaysign]]
```

further info click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx)